# not recieving notification on device even after registering for fcm token ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Below is my appdelegate (I'm using Swift 3). I am getting the fcm token and apns token successfully. Still notification is not appearing on the device. Can anyone help?

```
import UserNotifications
import Firebase


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    static var shared: AppDelegate { return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
        print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
        return true
    }


    func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {

        print(remoteMessage.appData)

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")

        }
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")

        }

        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    }
}


@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")

        }
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")

        }
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  -> I was also suffer from this problem. I show your code. It is look perfect.But you have to check some point like...

    1. Select Project (From Project Navigator)->Select Capabilities->On Push notification.
    2. Your google plist file must be correct.
    3. all things are done then run your latest application in ios device and then closed application.Even Removed from background.(If your application are in background then you can not show notification and most important you can not see notification in simulator.)
```

Comment: still i am not recieving notifications. I have checked these already. my app is just in the development stage. It has not yet been uploaded to apple. Will that be the problem? @Dhaval Solanki

Comment: your apple id must be paid.It is not problem uploaded or not.

Comment: then i don't no brother.this is same problem with me but when i fixed this issue push notification work in my project.

Comment: How do you send push notification? If you use Firebase console, you need to upload the APNs Auth Key to the console.

Comment: In my project push notification generated from API side. I am just put code in AppDelegate.